# In a list of date-time values, how can I get the elements with specific date (not datw-time)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a list of date-time values in `idxs` and a specific date in `target_day` variable. I need to get all the elements in `idxs` with that taget date + the time. So I need the `result` to be `['2020-09-20 07:00:00', '2020-09-20 13:00:00', '2020-09-20 19:00:00','2020-09-20 06:00:00', '2020-09-20 12:00:00', '2020-09-20 18:00:00']`.

```
idxs = ['2020-09-16 15:00:00', '2020-09-17 11:00:00', '2020-09-18 00:00:00', '2020-09-18 12:00:00', '2020-09-19 02:00:00', '2020-09-20 06:00:00', '2020-09-20 12:00:00', '2020-09-20 18:00:00', '2020-09-18 01:00:00', '2020-09-18 13:00:00', '2020-09-19 03:00:00', '2020-09-20 07:00:00', '2020-09-20 13:00:00', '2020-09-20 19:00:00']

idxs = [datetime.strptime(idx, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for idx in idxs]

target_day = '2020-09-20'
target_day = datetime.strptime(target_day, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

What I did is the following ugly code. Is there a better way to do it?

```
idxs_date_only = [datetime.strptime(idx, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() for idx in idxs]
idxs_date_time = [datetime.strptime(idx, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for idx in idxs]
if target_day in idxs_date_only:
    positive = [str(idx) for idx in idxs_date_time if datetime.strptime(str(idx), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() == target_day]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast solution is to work directly on the items as strings:

```
positive=[i for i in idxs if i[:10]==target_day]

>>> print(positive)

['2020-09-20 06:00:00', '2020-09-20 12:00:00', '2020-09-20 18:00:00', '2020-09-20 07:00:00', '2020-09-20 13:00:00', '2020-09-20 19:00:00']
```